# Adding has_one_attached and has_many_attached dynamically to a model on each request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activestorage

I am trying to add has_one_attached and has_many_attached
dynamically to a model on each request. I am able to do it, but probably there is a bug in the implementation, and I am looking for a better/correct way.

Here is my current setup. I have a products table that belongs to a shop model. A shop defines the attributes that a product can have using the custom_fields model.

Here is some code.

CustomField Model

```
# This model has mainly two attributes field_name and field_type. The records in this table are dynamic i.e., user-generated
# Here are some examples of the kind of records that can be stored:
# *) An icon field_name with image field_type
# *) manual field_name with file field_type
# *) assets field_name with multi_file field_type
# *) photos field_name with multi_image field_type
# *) product_name field_name with text type
# *) price field_name with number type
class CustomField < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Shop Model

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :custom_fields
  has_many :products
end
```

Product Model

```
# This model has a JSON column (field_data) to store non active_storage fields.
# For example fields like product_name and price information will be stored in the JSON column
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

ProductDecorator class. Instantiated on each request in a controller

```
class ProductDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  def initialize(object)
    super
    @custom_fields = shop.custom_fields
    init_fields
  end

  def init_fields
    # Save the non active_storage attributes to the JSON column.
    # Here I am adding the store_accessor to the singleton_class. On each request we have a different singleton_class
    __getobj__.singleton_class.class_eval do
      store_accessor :field_data, *simple_fields
    end

    # We can't use has_one_attached on a singleton_class class or at least I     couldn't figure out a way.
    # Here I am monkey patching the class to make it work on each request which needs to be avoided
    has_one_attached_fields.each do |field|
      __getobj__.class.class_eval do
        has_one_attached field
      end
    end

    # Same like above here are monkey patching the class on each request.
    has_many_attached_fields.each do |field|
      __getobj__.class.class_eval do
        has_many_attached field
      end
    end
  end

  def simple_fields
    non_scalar = %w[file image multi_file multi_image]
    @custom_fields.reject { |f| non_scalar.include? f.field_type }.pluck(:field_name)
  end

  def has_one_attached_fields
@custom_fields.select { |f| %w[file image].include? f.field_type }.pluck(:field_name)
  end

  def has_many_attached_fields
@custom_fields.select { |f| %w[multi_file multi_image].include? f.field_type }.pluck(:field_name)
  end
end
```

The product model is decorated with the ProductDecorator class to modify the Product behavior in a rails controller on each request.

Based on the custom_fields defined in the shop model, the decorator class adds the active_storage functionality to a model.

The current code will work but, the dynamically added functionality will live forever in the class and will not be cleaned up after the request as the methods are added to the class instead of a singleton class.

I looked into ruby refinements but couldn't come up with a solution yet. Another option that I have is to sidestep active_storage completely and build custom rails models but would like to use active_storage if possible.

Is there any better way? Any help in this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are probably better off creating a model to connect attachments and products. Something like `product_attachments attachment:references product:references slot:string` then you can do some nested_attributes stuff to make it work probably.

Comment: Makes sense @RolandStuder. Probably that's the way I will go if I can't find any solution. Thanks

Comment: Yeah @RolandStuder is definately right here.  `has_one_attached` and `has_many_attached` are class level and this would just create chaos if the class is held in memory for multiple requests. Anything per request should always be instance level.